# How to update the component of a master page with changes that happen on its detail page immediately?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a nativescript angular app.

Suppose you have a page A (call it master) that has a list of items. B is a detail of A, that shows a particular item. Let say a list of cars, with the prices shown in the list page.
Then the user changes the price on the details page, and comes back to the master page.
In my app what happens is the master page is updated accordingly, but in a lazy way.
The user basically sees a list that changes after that comes back. This is most probably to the way angular triggers the component update, only after the users hits "back".

Is there a way to force the master page to be updated before the user clicks "back"?
More specifically, I would like that this kind of update to not be lazy, but eager.

Comment: Please share more details how you are updating them, either by service / state / both page share the same data object, possibly with some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using {N}+Angular, then the common practice is to use an emitter from your child component to signal your parent that some event happened inside the child component.

so on your parent.html component you'd have something like:

```
<child (listener)="onEmitterReceivedFunction(objReceived)"></child>
```

with this on the parent.ts:

```
onEmitterReceivedFunction(objReceived) {
   // Do what has to be done 
}
```

then on your child.ts you'd have something like:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core"

@Output('listener') onSomethingChanged = new EventEmitter<any>()

whenSomethingChanged() {
    onSomethingChanged.emit(this.thingThatChanged)
}
```

These are of course snippets that you'll have to put in the right places of your code.

For more details you can look at: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter